# Converting date to epoch time in clojure or jython

Tags: clojure, jython, epoch, openrefine

I am looking for formula to convert a date to epoch time in OpenRefine. I know GREL language doesn't support this but I wonder if clojure or jython does, and if so how?

I am not familiar with those languages at all.

For now I am using API call with [this service](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/), but this is a lengthy process with large data set.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got the solution off the [OpenRefine mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openrefine/p5gfbsvJzBo/JY8hAY_KkscJ). I've been converting string to date and used

```
value.toDate('dd-MM-yy','dd-MMM-yy').toString('dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 4):

make a date object for the time you desire (it defaults to now) and then call .getTime on it:

```
user> (.getTime (java.util.Date.))                                         
1361830209902
```

or if you want the epoch time for a specific date:

```
user> (import java.text.SimpleDateFormat) 
user> (.getTime (.parse (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy MM dd HH mm ss") "2013 02 25 04 06 59"))
1361794019000
```

Comment: OK I will see how I can install `SimpleDateFormat` for OpenRefine, thanks

Comment: Setting the language to Clojure for the transform and using `(.getTime value)` worked for me in OpenRefine.

Answer (score 1):

[clj-time](http://seancorfield.github.com/clj-time/doc/clj-time.coerce.html#var-to-long) (JodaTime) is preferable for datetime manipulation:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as cljt])
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as cljc])

(cljc/to-long (cljt/now))
```

Comment: I had no idea that `clj-time.coerce` even existed.

Answer (score 0):

For Python (including Jython implementation) you can use `time` module:

```
import time
print(time.mktime(time.strptime('2012-02-12 12:34:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in OpenRefine by performing a transform on the date column, setting the language to Clojure and using this command:

```
(.getTime value)
```

very similar to @arthur-ulfeldt's answer, but wanted to clarify things specifically for OpenRefine.